# how to effectively test for valid string input using getopts in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, getopts

I'm using `getopts` in my bash script to pass in 2 parameters.

I'm trying to enforce a string match (using if statement) on my input for `-c <component>` to enter the following options:

Note: it has to match the exact string for these 5 options:

```
customer_builder
customer_service
historic_customer_builder
stream_builder
data_distributor
```

**Code in progress:**

```
# Usage for getopts
usage () {
    echo -e "Usage:$0 -r region -c <component>"
    echo -e "Available components:"
    echo -e "customer_builder|customer_service|historic_customer_builder|stream_builder|data_distributor"
    echo -e "Example:$0 -r us-east-1 -c customer_builder"
}

while getopts ":r:c:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    r) region="$OPTARG";;
    c) component="$OPTARG"
       if [[ "${c}" != "customer_builder" && "${c}" != "customer_service" && "${c}" != "historic_customer_builder" && "${c}" != "stream_builder" && "${c}" != "data_distributor" ]]; then
         usage
         exit 1
       fi
       ;;
    *) usage
       exit 1
       ;;
  esac
done
```

**The main logic I am trying to use and need help with:**

```
   if [[ "${c}" != "customer_builder" && "${c}" != "customer_service" && "${c}" != "historic_customer_builder" && "${c}" != "stream_builder" && "${c}" != "data_distributor" ]]; then
     usage
     exit 1
   fi
```

So in my testing, I cannot get the string to be enforced.

I expect to get `usage` if I enter the string incorrectly:

```
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c customer-builder
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c customer
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c builder
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c foo_bar
```

However, I should expect the script to execute if I enter it correctly:

```
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c customer_builder
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c customer_service
./script.sh -r us-east-1 -c stream_builder
```

So my question is how would you handle and check for proper string input?
Is there a better way to write my test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing the wrong parameter. `$c` isn't defined, but you just saved  `-c`'s argument in `$component`.

---

That said, another another `case` statement might be simper than your long `if` condition, and doesn't rely on `bash` extensions.

```
case $component in
  customer_builder|\
  customer_service|\
  historic_customer_builder|\
  stream_builder|\
  data_distributor)
    :  # Do nothing
    ;;
  *)
    usage
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

OK, now that I've gotten try-to-stay-POSIX-compatible out of my system, here's a simpler `if` statement using `[[...]]`'s pattern matching abilities. (This will work as-is in newer versions of `bash`; older versions will require `shopt -s extglob` to enable the `@(...)` syntax.)

```
if [[ $component != @(customer_builder|customer_service|historic_customer_builder|stream_builder|data_distributor) ]]; then
```

Comment: thanks for your input.  for the `if` statement, i'm looking to test if its NOT any of those options, then got to `usage` - do we need to add `!=`

Comment: Ah, right. Yes, use `!=` instead, or negate the entire test (`if ! [[ $component = ... ]]; then`).